# running into a problem with Webscraping using bs4

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, typeerror

in this program, I get an error saying "slice indices must be integers or none or have an **_index** method". Anyone knows why? Thanks in advance!

```
import requests, html.parser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B005EWTL7C'

headers = {"User-Agent" :'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(link, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser').encode("utf-8")
price = soup.find("span", "a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockSalePriceString").get_text()
#converted = price[0:4]
#print(converted)
```

Comment: .your error occur because of `.encode("utf-8")`. if you remove `.encode("utf-8")` this type error will be gone.

Comment: @HumayunAhmadRajib but now it gives another error saying AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: I saw your url, I did not see `a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockSalePriceString` there.You will see that `a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockSalePriceString` is correct!

Comment: @HumayunAhmadRajib aren't those two the same?

Comment: did you see `a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockSalePriceString` this attribute in the html code?

Comment: @HumayunAhmadRajib yes, that's the class of the price $56.99 in the html code

Comment: Please use `price = soup.find("span", "a-size-medium a-color-price")` instead of `price = soup.find("span", "a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockSalePriceString")`, I think it will work.